# how to set 'warm-up period' in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, warm-up

I want to set the warm-up period in AnyLogic Personal Learning Edition. I searched for the warm-up period place in AnyLogic, but I couldn't find any thing about the warm-up period.

Is there a warm up period in Anylogic or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default warm-up setting as it would not make sense given the vast flexibility of the tool and user needs.

It is easy, however, to set it up yourself. As usual, there are many different options, here is one:

1. create a variable v_WarmupDuration on Main, set it to whatever many time units you need
2. any data object you want to only record after the warmup period, ensure it only captures data if `time() > v_WarmupDuration`.

Events can have a custom initial time which you can use v_WarmupDuration for.
Functions that log data can only do so if `time() > v_WarmupDuration`, and so on.

Alternatively, log all your data as normal but add time stamps to them. Then, you can

Answer (score 0):

Creating a warmup variable works fine for metrics you create yourself.

But if you want to use the built in functionality like histograms created from timeMeasureStart and timeMeasureEnd blocks in Anylogic, you will also need to add an extra select option so e.g. assuming you set v_WarmupDuration to 60 minutes, then you need a select block with a decision on false that goes straight to sink block or the next element after the timeMeasureEnd.

Condition if true: time(MINUTE) > v_warmupDuration

That way, the warmup period will not accumulate into the dataset of the timeMeasureEnd.

If you want to set this as a parmeter to an experiment, then ...

1. Add a variable to the experiment page off the screen e.g. v_warmupMins
2. Add a control like a slider on the experiment page and link to the variable v_warmupMins
3. Add a parameter to hold the warmup time in the Main canvas e.g. p_warmupMins
4. On the experiment properties, set the parameter p_warmupMins = v_warmupMins
5. to programmatically add this time onto the StopTime, add this to the Before Simulation Runs
   getEngine().setStopTime( getEngine().getStopTime(MINUTE) + v_warmupMins );

Now when i run experiment with slider set to 60 mins, it adds 60 mins onto the stoptime and runs the experiment without accumulating metrics until that time has passed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok - note that this is not working as expected.  On first run it works but on subsequent runs, it adds the warmup time to the value left from the previous run.  Maybe also need to store the stopTime minutes and time and set those accordingly as well - I havent worked it out yet.

Comment: Would be nice if anylogic took care of warmup periods which are likely to be needed in many types of simulation.  It also doesnt seem to let you set a negative startTime as that would help.  If you could do that, you could set start time to be -120 mins e.g. to start two hours before your configured time so if running for a day, a week or a month, the measured times would correspond to the time you want to measure.